# Как отпилить в строке ненужную длину символов

Tags: javascript, строки

Результат вывода программы "ЗАШИФРОВАТЬ ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУ ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУМЕТОДОМ ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУМЕТОДОМВИЖЕНЕРА" не знаю как обрезать определенное количество символов при новом цикле у строки. Т.е чтоб в завершении выводило ЗАШИФРОВАТЬ СТРОКУ МЕТОДОМ ВИЖЕНЕРА. Количество символов которых нужно обрезать лежит в переменной count и увеличивается с каждой итерацией цикла. метод slpice не работает так как работа идет с строкой а не с массивом. Направьте в нужно русло буду благодарен)

```js
var arrText = ["11", "6", "7", "8"];
var lengthOfText = 32;
function breakOfText(s) {
  console.log(arrText); //(4) ["11", "6", "7", "8"];
  console.log(arrText.length); // 4
  console.log(lengthOfText); //32

  var INPUT = s;
  var b = [];
  var arrayOutput = [];
  var splits = "";

  var count = 0;
  const ZERO = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
    count += +arrText[i]; // старая длина слова + новая длина слова
    console.log(count);
    for (var j = 0; j < lengthOfText; j++) {
      splits += INPUT[j]; //добавлять символы до тех пор пока не будет равно длинне [i] слова
      if (j == count - 1) {

        splits += ' ';
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(splits); //result
}

breakOfText('ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУМЕТОДОМВИЖЕНЕРА');
```

Comment: будьте благодарны: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp,  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: @igor возможно плохо объяснил я. но мне нужно удалить а не вернуть эту часть строки

Comment: поясните, какую строку в каком месте кода Вы хотите обрезать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "ЗАШИФРОВАТЬ ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУ ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУМЕТОДОМ ЗАШИФРОВАТЬСТРОКУМЕТОДОМВИЖЕНЕРА";

var arr = str.split(' ');

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = arr.map((item, i) => {
  return !i ? item : item.slice(arr[i - 1].length);
}).join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```